# Without using $c, a\rightarrow 0\!,$ prove that $\forall_{b}\exists_{a\,b\,c}\;a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc\geq\left | 2ca \right |$

Tags: inequality, logic

> Without using $c, a\rightarrow 0\!,$ prove that
> $$\forall_{b}\exists_{a\,b\,c}\;a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc\geq\left | 2ca \right |$$
> Source: StackMath/@haidangel

*My proof*. Choose $a, b, c:= a- b, b- b, c- b$ so that
$$a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc- 2ca= \left ( \,c- a\, \right )^{\!2}\geq 0$$
$$a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc+ 2ca= \left ( c+ a- 2b \right )^{2}$$
How about your plans of solving this kind of inequality ? I want to know them, thanks a real lot !

Comment: The original statement isn't well formed because $b$ is in two quantifiers. Also it would be easier to follow your assertions if you used letters other than $a,b,c$ for the values you want to choose.

Comment: @haidangel Actually I don't understand your solution. I let $a = x - y, b = 0, c = z - y$ and get $a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc- 2ca = (z - x)^2$. Your notation confuses me.

Comment: @haidangel Also, $\forall_{b}\exists_{a\,b\,c}$, do you mean $\forall_{b}\exists_{a\,c}$? In other words, for any given $b$ (fixed), there exist $a, c$ such that ...

Comment: "Choose $a, b, c:= a- b, b- b, c- b$": that is horrible! Who knows which $b$ you're referring to when you say $b$? Please correct it by choosing new names for your new variables.

Comment: @haidangel If you want $a,c$ of opposite signs, take $a=-c$. If you want them of the same sign, take $a=3c$. In either case the inequality will hold for any values of $b,c$.

Comment: The notation is confusing. What is meant by $b:=b-b$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the LHS of the inequality as a quadratic function of $b$ :
$$f(b) =b^2 -(a+c)b+(a^2+c^2-2|ac|) \ge0 \tag{1}$$

$(1)$ holds true if and only if the $\Delta$ of $f(b)$ is not positive and
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta &= (a+c)^2 -4(a^2+c^2-2|ac|)\\
&= -3a^2+(8|ac|+2ac)-3c^2 \\
\end{align}
$$

For all $a,c$ such that $ac <0$, we have $\Delta = -3(a+c)^2 \le0$. So, we can conclude that for all $b$, we can chose $a,c$ such that $ac<0$ and the inequality holds true.
Q.E.D